# Node Red CBOR Tagged JSON filter

Tags: node-red

I searched some more and found out that i need to split the input data.
Eventually this seems to work:

`[{"id":"41df16a7.324d4","type":"tab","label":"Flow 1","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"c8d8e6d8.178c68","type":"udp in","z":"41df16a7.324d4","name":"","iface":"","port":"2019","ipv":"udp4","multicast":"false","group":"","datatype":"buffer","x":80,"y":1140,"wires":[["f1a463dd.53347"]]},{"id":"f1a463dd.53347","type":"CBOR","z":"41df16a7.324d4","name":"","x":190,"y":1240,"wires":[["7a96c8d6.7e9098"]]},{"id":"8894a8e1.e04458","type":"function","z":"41df16a7.324d4","name":"Filter gps","func":"msg.payload=msg.payload[0].g.value\n\nreturn {\npayload:{\n    lon:msg.payload[1],\n    lat:msg.payload[0],\n    name:\"Dirksen\",\n    popped: true\n}\n}\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":540,"y":1140,"wires":[["5744bbba.0f6764","412e98a6.df7da8"]]},{"id":"5744bbba.0f6764","type":"worldmap","z":"41df16a7.324d4","name":"","lat":"0","lon":"0","zoom":"","layer":"OSM grey","cluster":"","maxage":"","usermenu":"show","layers":"show","panit":"false","panlock":"false","zoomlock":"false","hiderightclick":"false","coords":"none","showgrid":"false","path":"/worldmap","x":780,"y":1240,"wires":[]},{"id":"7a96c8d6.7e9098","type":"split","z":"41df16a7.324d4","name":"","splt":"\\120","spltType":"str","arraySplt":"1","arraySpltType":"len","stream":false,"addname":"","x":290,"y":1140,"wires":[["efa46aa3.c049c8"]]},{"id":"efa46aa3.c049c8","type":"sort","z":"41df16a7.324d4","name":"","order":"ascending","as_num":false,"target":"payload","targetType":"msg","msgKey":"payload[0].g.value","msgKeyType":"jsonata","seqKey":"payload","seqKeyType":"msg","x":410,"y":1240,"wires":[["8894a8e1.e04458"]]},{"id":"412e98a6.df7da8","type":"debug","z":"41df16a7.324d4","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","x":750,"y":1140,"wires":[]}]`

It is probably very crude solution, but it does the trick, thanks!

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the 24 bytes in the buffer (if you click on it in the debug sidebar it should list the out) from the HTTP-In node then we can try and reproduce the output.

Comment: I see! I earlier used this trick to filter another object value: `msg.payload = msg.payload[1].vs` . I will try this tomorrow.

Comment: Alas, the trick is not possible, i do net get object values, i get: `msg.payload : Tagged

"120([{"t":22,"v":4215,"o":"20408","g":{"tag":103,"value":[0,0,0]}}])"`  .                               If i copy and paste path, i only see "payload" in the function lines. It is not an object apparently so the seperate items can not be seperated?

Comment: A few minutes later the gps has made a fix, i get: `msg.payload : Tagged

"120([{"t":21,"v":4215,"o":"20408","g":{"tag":103,"value":[51.365726470947266,6.174952983856201,2]}}])"
` . That is ok, only i would like to isolate the gps parameters. The lte module uses cbor payload. The flow uses UDP input (buffer), cbor node, then json node(Always convert to javascript object. The json output is mentioned above.

Comment: As I asked  in the first comment please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59236639/edit) the question (do not add as a comment) to include the expanded values from the `msg.payload` buffer in the first debug output. This way I can test your input into the CBOR node. Once I have that will be able to answer the question.